# Solving an ODE with Laplace transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

One question, can you solve an ODE of type $y'''+y''\cdots =0$ with Laplace transforms if you don't get the values of $y_0$?

I've tried it but there are many unknowns.

Thanks

Comment: You should post the differential equation so you can get some help. Normally you should have three constants for a linear diff equation of order three.

Comment: There is no unique solution to a generic third-order ODE; rather, the general solution is parametrized by the initial conditions $y_0,y_0',y_0''$. That's true whether or not you solve with Laplace transforms.

Comment: Is there an issue with just leaving the initial conditions as variables and Laplace transforming anyways? The algebra is identical.

Comment: @Isham $y'''+y'=0$

Comment: It can be made easy the way you look for the homogeneous solution and then the particular one. But there are also the constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $y:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is $n+1$-times differentiable. We compute
$$
\mathcal L(y'(t)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}y'(t)\ \mathsf dt = e^{-st}y(t)|_0^\infty + s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y(t)\ \mathsf dt = Y(s) - y(0).
$$
Assume now that $\mathcal L(y^{(n)}(t)) = s^n Y(s) - \sum_{j=1}^n y^{(n-j)}(0)s^{j-1}$ for some nonnegative integer $n$. Then 
\begin{align}
\mathcal L(y^{(n+1)}(t)) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st}y^{(n+1)}(t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= e^{-st}y^{(n)}|_0^\infty + s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y^{(n)}(t)\ \mathsf dt\\
&= y^{(n)}(0) + s\mathcal L(y^{(n)}(t))\\
&= y^{(n)}(0) + s(s^n Y(s) - \sum_{j=1}^n y^{(n-j)}(0)s^{j-1}\\
&= s^{n+1}Y(s) + y^{(n)}(0) - \sum_{j=1}^n y^{(n-j)}(0)s^j\\
&= S^{n+1}Y(s) + \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} y^{n+1-j}(0)s^{j-1},
\end{align}
so by mathematical induction, the formula holds true for all nonnegative integers. Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^m a_iy^{(i)}(t) = 0$, then
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_iy^{(i)}(t)\right) &= \sum_{i=0}^m a_i\mathcal L(y^{(i)}(t)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^m a_i \left(s^i Y(s) - \sum_{j=1}^i y^{(i-j)}(0)s^{j-1}\right)\\
&= Y(s)\sum_{i=0}^m a_is^i - \sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=i} y^{(i-j)}(0)s^{j-1}\\
&= Y(s)\sum_{i=0}^m a_is^i - \sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{i=j}^m y^{(i-j)}(0)s^{j-1}\\
&= Y(s)\sum_{i=0}^m a_is^i - \sum_{j=1}^m s^{j-1} \sum_{i=0}^{m-j}y^{(i)}(0).
\end{align}
Now, since $\mathcal L\left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_iy^{(i)}(t)\right)=0$, we have
$$
Y(s) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^m s^{j-1} \sum_{i=0}^{m-j}y^{(i)}(0)}{\sum_{i=0}^m a_is^i}.
$$
As you can see, we can compute the Laplace transform, but cannot solve the ODE without knowledge of the values of $y^{(i)}(0)$.